# Python, takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Im to trying run a Python script in Spyder IDE (Python 3.6) and as I progress Im starting to refactor it to more of OOP (Object Oriented) and hopefully a mature package.

**I have a class titled (Epoch), see below:**

```
class Epoch:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Epoch_Counter = 0 
        self.Timings = [] 
        self.Timings_millisec_ticks = [] 
        self.Duration_milli_secs = 0 
        self.Raw = []
        self.Stimulia = []
        self.Majority_stimulia = "NA"
        self.epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
        #median, positive area, negative area, geometric,max,ratio positive vs negative
        self._median = 0 
        self._mean = 0 
        self._positive_area = 0
        self._negative_area = 0 
        self._geometric_area = 0 
        self._max = 0 
        self._min = 0 
        self._max_amplitude = 0
        self._integral = 0 
        self._variance= 0 
        self._positive_to_negative_ratio = 0 
        self._skew = 0 
        self._kurtosis = 0 
        self.Components = [] 


    #mean
    def mean(self,value):
        self._mean = value

    def mean(self):
        return self._mean

    #median
    def median(self,value):
        self._median = value

    def median(self):
        return self._median

    #positive_area 
    def positive_area(self,value):
        self._positive_area = value


    def positive_area(self):
        return self._positive_area

    #negative_area
    def negative_area(self,value):
        self._negative_area = value


    def negative_area(self):
        return self._negative_area

    #geometric_area
    def geometric_area(self,value):
        self._geometric_area = value

    def geometric_area(self):
        return self._geometric_area

    def integral(self,value):
        self.integral = value

    def integral(self):
        return self.integral

    def max_amplitude(self,value):
        self._max_amplitude = value

    def max_amplitude(self):
        return self._max_amplitude

    def max_(self,value):
        self._max = value

    def max_(self):
        return self._max

    #min 
    def min_(self,value):
        self.min = value

    def min_(self):
        return self._min

    def positive_to_negative_ratio(self,value):
        self.positive_to_negative_ratio = value

    def positive_to_negative_ratio(self,value):
        return self._positive_to_negative_ratio

    #Timings_millisec_ticks
    def timings_millisec_ticks(self):
        return self.Timings_millisec_ticks

    def timings_millisec_ticks_append(self,value):
        self.Timings_millisec_ticks.append(value)

    #start_time
    def timings(self):
        return self.Timings

    def timings_append(self,value):
        self.Timings.append(value)

    #end_time
    def end_time(self):
        return self.Timings[len(self.Timings)-1]

    #start_time
    def start_time(self):
        return self.Timings[0]

    #duration 
    def duration_milli_secs(self):
        return self.Duration_milli_secs

    def duration_milli_secs(self):
        return self.unix_time_millis(self.str_to_datetime_(self.end_time())) - self.unix_time_millis(self.str_to_datetime_(self.start_time()))

    #raw
    def raw(self):
        return self.Raw

    def raw_append(self,value):
        self.Raw.append(value)

    #components
    def components(self):
        return self.Components

    def components_append(self,value):
        self.Components.append(value)

    #stimulia
    def stimulia_append(self,value):
        self.Stimulia.append(value)

    def stimulia(self):
        return self.Stimulia

    #variance 
    def variance(self):
        return self.variance

    def variance(self,value):
        self.variance = value

    #skew
    def skew(self,value):
        self._skew = value

    def skew(self):
        return self._skew

    def unix_time_millis(self,dt):
        return (dt - self.epoch).total_seconds() * 1000.0

    """ covert datetime of this format 2017-10-13 19:22:50:525 to datetime object"""
    def  str_to_datetime_(self,datetime_str):
     return datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

    def _print(self):
        return str(self.Epoch_Counter)+","+str(len(self.Timings))+","+str(self.duration_milli_secs())+","+str(len(self.Raw))+","+str(len(self.Stimulia))+","+str(self.majority_stimulia)
```

I have script that has function, that calculates summary statistics and attempts to set the value of the statistics in the Epoch object (mean,median,etc...), see below:

```
def get_epoch_summary_stats(eeg_record_epochs_):
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.stats as stats
    import pylab as pl
    ##stimulia
    stimulia_raw_median = []
    stimulia_raw_mean = [] 
    stimulia_raw_positive_area = [] 
    stimulia_raw_negative_area = []
    stimulia_raw_geometric_area = []
    stimulia_raw_max = [] 
    stimulia_raw_min = [] 
    stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative = []
    stimulia_variance = []
    stimulia_max_amplitude = [] 
    stimulia_integral = []
    stimulia_raw_kurtosis = [] 
    stimulia_raw_skew = []

    ##no stimulia
    no_stimulia_raw_median = []
    no_stimulia_raw_mean = []
    no_stimulia_raw_positive_area = [] 
    no_stimulia_raw_negative_area = []
    no_stimulia_raw_geometric_area = []
    no_stimulia_raw_max = [] 
    no_stimulia_raw_min = [] 
    no_stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative = []
    no_stimulia_variance = [] 
    no_stimulia_max_amplitude = [] 
    no_stimulia_integral = []
    no_stimulia_raw_kurtosis = [] 
    no_stimulia_raw_skew = []

    no_stimulia_class_count = 0 
    stimulia_class_count = 0


    epoch_durations = [] 

    stimulia_raws = []  
    no_stimulia_raws = [] 

    for item in eeg_record_epochs: 
        epoch_durations.append(item.duration_milli_secs())


    epoch_durations_sorted = sorted(epoch_durations)
    mean_duration = np.mean(epoch_durations_sorted)
    std_duration = np.std(epoch_durations_sorted)


    print("Input data:",path)


    print("Epoch duration(millisecs) - mean_duration:",mean_duration)
    print("Epoch duration(millisecs) - std_duration:",std_duration)
    #remove epoch that are more than 1 standard deviation away from the mean in epoch size 
    counter = 0
    for item in eeg_record_epochs_: 
        ##DURATION SELECTION RULE 
        if (item.duration_milli_secs() > (mean_duration + std_duration) or item.duration_milli_secs() < (mean_duration - std_duration)):
            del eeg_record_epochs[counter]
            ##print("epoch duration_milli_secs - REMOVED:",item.duration_milli_secs())
        else:

            ##print("epoch duration_milli_secs:",item.duration_milli_secs())
            #median, positive area, negative area, geometric area, max , ratio positive vs negative, ratio negative vs positive 
            raw_float_array = np.array(item.raw()).astype(np.float)
            #median
            item.median(np.median(raw_float_array))
            #mean 
            item.mean(np.mean(raw_float_array))
            ##print("raw median: ",item.median)
            positive_area = 0
            negative_area = 0
            #positive area
            for value in raw_float_array:
                if value > 0:
                    positive_area = positive_area + value

            item.positive_area(positive_area)
            ##print("raw positive_area:", item.positive_area)
            #negative area
            for value in raw_float_array:
                if value < 0 :
                    negative_area = negative_area + abs(value)

            item.negative_area(negative_area)
            ##print("raw negative_area:", item.negative_area)
            #geometric area 
            abs_raw_float_array = np.abs(raw_float_array)
            item.geometric_area(sum(abs_raw_float_array))
            ##print("raw geometric_area:", item.geometric_area)

            #max_
            item.max(max(raw_float_array))
            ##print("raw max_:",item.max_)
            #min
            item.min(min(raw_float_array))

            item.max_amplitude(max(max(raw_float_array),abs(min(raw_float_array))))

            item.integral(item.positive_area - abs(item.negative_area))
            ##print("raw min_:",item.min_)
            #min
            #positive_to_negative_ratio
            try:
                item.positive_to_negative_ratio=abs(item.positive_area/item.negative_area)
            except ZeroDivision as err:
                continue

            #variance 
            item.variance(np.var(raw_float_array))

            #skew
            item.skew(stats.skew(raw_float_array))

            #kurtosis
            item.kurtosis(stats.kurtosis(raw_float_array))

            ##print("raw positive_to_negative:",item.positive_to_negative_ratio)
            item.majority_stimulia()
            ##default NO_STIMULIA
            stimulia_class = "NO_STIMULIA"


            if  item.majority_stimulia().upper() == "ON":
                stimulia_class = "ON"
                print(stimulia_class)
                item.plot()


                for raw_value in item.raw():
                    stimulia_raws.append(int(raw_value))

                stimulia_raw_median.append(item.median) 
                stimulia_raw_mean.append(item.mean)
                stimulia_raw_positive_area.append(item.positive_area)
                stimulia_raw_negative_area.append(item.negative_area)
                stimulia_raw_geometric_area.append(item.geometric_area)
                stimulia_raw_max.append(item.max_)
                stimulia_raw_min.append(item.min_)
                stimulia_raw_mean.append(item.mean)
                stimulia_raw_skew.append(item.skew)
                stimulia_raw_kurtosis.append(item.kurtosis)
                stimulia_max_amplitude.append(item.max_amplitude)
                stimulia_integral.append(item.integral)
                ##append only if the number is not inf or nan but just a number 
                if is_not_inf_or_is_nan(item.positive_to_negative_ratio) != 1:
                    stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative.append(item.positive_to_negative_ratio)
                    ##print("item.positive_to_negative_ratio:",item.positive_to_negative_ratio)
                stimulia_variance.append(item.variance)
                stimulia_class_count=  stimulia_class_count + 1
                #P3 component stats +/- estimated peek for P3



            else:
                no_stimulia_class_count = no_stimulia_class_count + 1
                print(stimulia_class)
                item.plot()
                for raw_value in item.raw():
                    no_stimulia_raws.append(int(raw_value))

                no_stimulia_raw_median.append(item.median) 
                no_stimulia_raw_mean.append(item.mean)
                no_stimulia_raw_positive_area.append(item.positive_area)
                no_stimulia_raw_negative_area.append(item.negative_area)
                no_stimulia_raw_geometric_area.append(item.geometric_area)
                no_stimulia_raw_max.append(item.max_)
                no_stimulia_raw_min.append(item.min_)
                no_stimulia_raw_mean.append(item.mean)
                no_stimulia_raw_skew.append(item.skew)
                no_stimulia_raw_kurtosis.append(item.kurtosis)
                no_stimulia_max_amplitude.append(item.max_amplitude)
                no_stimulia_integral.append(item.integral)
                ##append only if the number is not inf or nan but just a number
                if is_not_inf_or_is_nan(item.positive_to_negative_ratio) != 1:
                    no_stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative.append(item.positive_to_negative_ratio)
                    ##print("item.positive_to_negative_ratio:",item.positive_to_negative_ratio)
                no_stimulia_variance.append(item.variance)

            ##print("majority stimulia:",item.Majority_stimulia)


            counter = counter + 1
            ##component_extraction(item,"ON",300,200,800)

    print("ON summary stats-")

    mean_plot = float(sum(stimulia_raw_mean)/counter)
    std_plot = float(math.sqrt(sum(stimulia_variance)/counter))
    fit = stats.norm.pdf(sorted(stimulia_raws), mean_plot, std_plot)  #this is a fitting indeed
    pl.plot(sorted(stimulia_raws),fit,'-o')
    pl.hist(sorted(stimulia_raws),normed=True)      #use this to draw histogram of your data
    pl.show() 



    print("stimulia_class_count:",stimulia_class_count)
    print("average stimulia_raw_mean:",sum(stimulia_raw_mean)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_raw_median:",sum(stimulia_raw_median)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_raw_positive_area:",sum(stimulia_raw_positive_area)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_raw_negative_area:",sum(stimulia_raw_negative_area)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_raw_geometric_are:",sum(stimulia_raw_geometric_area)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_raw_max:",sum(stimulia_raw_max)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_raw_min:",sum(stimulia_raw_min)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_max_amplitude:",sum(stimulia_max_amplitude)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_integral:",sum(stimulia_integral)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_variance:",sum(stimulia_variance)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_std:",math.sqrt(sum(stimulia_variance)/counter))
    print("average stimulia_skew:",sum(stimulia_raw_skew)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_kurtosis:",sum(stimulia_raw_kurtosis)/counter)
    print("average stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative:",sum(stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative)/counter)

    print("NO_STIMULIA summary stats-")

    mean_plot = float(sum(no_stimulia_raw_mean)/counter)
    std_plot = float(math.sqrt(sum(no_stimulia_variance)/counter))
    fit = stats.norm.pdf(sorted(no_stimulia_raws), mean_plot, std_plot)  #this is a fitting indeed
    pl.plot(sorted(no_stimulia_raws),fit,'-o')
    pl.hist(sorted(no_stimulia_raws),normed=True)      #use this to draw histogram of your data
    pl.show()

    print("no_stimulia_class_count:",no_stimulia_class_count)
    print("average no_stimulia_raw_mean:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_mean)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_raw_median:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_median)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_raw_positive_area:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_positive_area)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_raw_negative_area:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_negative_area)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_raw_geometric_are:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_geometric_area)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia__raw_max:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_max)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_raw_min:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_min)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_max_amplitude:",sum(no_stimulia_max_amplitude)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_integral:",sum(no_stimulia_integral)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_variance:",sum(no_stimulia_variance)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_std:",math.sqrt(sum(no_stimulia_variance)/counter))
    print("average no_stimulia_skew:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_skew)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_kurtosis:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_kurtosis)/counter)
    print("average no_stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative:",sum(no_stimulia_raw_positive_to_negative)/counter)
```

When running the script, I get an error:

File "", line 1, in 
    get_epoch_summary_stats(eeg_record_epochs)

File "", line 425, in get_epoch_summary_stats
    item.median(np.median(raw_float_array))

**TypeError: median() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

**How can I fix the Epoch class or my call to item.median() in order to set Epoch's median attribute without getting this error.**

Thanks a million!

Comment: What made you think your class can have two methods with the same name?

Comment: You have `def median()` twice - one version takes an argument, the other does not.

Comment: Provide a minimal, viable example. Also, you're trying to do method polymorphism which doesn't exist in python (at least not in the way you're trying to do). For that you should look at **properties**.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I suspect this is because they learned to code in another language: Python does not support overloading.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Not really interested in speculations, sorry.

Comment: Python != Java ... You should just delete all your methods and just use `my_object.my_attribute` and `my_object.my_attribute = whatever`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method overloading in python. If you define `median` function twice, the second definition will be used. Therefore in your code, the second definition is used, i.e.,

```
def median(self):
    return self._median
```

So it only takes one positional argument (self).

It seems what you want to define is a getter and a setter. In python, you can do it by adding functional decorators. For example:

```
@property
def median(self):
    return self._median

@median.setter
def median(self, value):
    self._median = value
```

The first one is a getter for `median`, and the second one is a setter. When you invoke `print(self.median)`, the first function will be called, while if you execute `self.median = 5`, the second function will be called.

You can read this article for more information about getter and setters in python: http://stackabuse.com/python-properties/

Comment: This is not how the OP is currently using `self.median`, but this is the correct way to do what the OP wants to do.

Comment: That's right. THanks for the clarification.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I would say the *correct* way is *not to use properties until you need to actually control access*. As it stands, the Pythonic way is simply to omit all of these methods

Comment: @TemporalWolf, I updated my Epoch class , now when I run the code I get:     item.median(np.median(raw_float_array))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable , I read on stackoverflow that since median is being set to 0 in constructor "median=0" then median is being treated as a int rather than function.

Comment: @AryanNaim Because it's an attribute, not a function: `item.median = np.median(raw_float_array))`

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `median` two times:

```
#median
def median(self,value):
    self._median = value

def median(self):
    return self._median
```

The second definition is used, which does not accept a second argument named `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer as he was correct. Try to focus on changing your functions to getters and setters. Should help out in the long run.